# image resizing in shell script in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

i have two images. i created a .sh file for manipulate it. First i use a for loop for that..

My director structure:-

test
  image
     doc
     newimage
     angelimage
     test.sh
     5elements10.png
     boltonclinics5.png

Now i want the 2 images to composite with a 3rd.png both and store in **newimage** after that i want the images in the **newimage** folder are converted to a perticular angel.
So i try with the code

```
   #!/bin/bash
for f in $( ls *.png ); do
  composite -gravity center $f ./doc/back.png ./newimage/new$f
done 
for f in `ls ./newimage`; do

  convert $f -rotate -7 ./angelimage/ang$f
done
```

now i found that the for  loop works properly, but the second one give an error like this bellow

```
convert: unable to open image `new-5elements10.png':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.
convert: unable to open file `new-5elements10.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3234.
convert: missing an image filename `new-5elements10.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
convert: unable to open image `new-boltonclinics5.png':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.
convert: unable to open file `new-boltonclinics5.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3234.
convert: missing an image filename `new-boltonclinics5.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use ls(1) to produce lists of files that are fed to commands. Simple glob expansion is enough (as shown below).

Quote your variables to prevent whitespace problems.

If there isn't any other logical error in your code, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.png;
do
    composite -gravity center "$f" ./doc/back.png "./newimage/new${f}"
done 

for f in ./newimage/*;
do
    convert -rotate -7 "$f" "./angelimage/ang$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Comment: convert "$f" -rotate -7 "./angelimage/ang${f}" is not working as previous. when i add ls $f it works, but not work the above code

Comment: now i add this for keep the two image in a new folder named finalimage in the last for loopfor f in ./newimage/*;
do
    convert -rotate -7 "$f" "./angelimage/a$(basename "$f")"
    echo $f;
    composite -geometry +200+130 "$f" "./angelimage/a$(basename "$f")" "./finalimage/final${f}"
done, but did not work